# Removing all predicates of a given subject via SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, triplestore

I am trying to delete a known URI from our triplestore. It can be a subject or an object, by its predicates. So what I like to do is the following:

```
DELETE { 
    GRAPH <graph> {
        <uri> ?p1 ?o1 .
        ?s2 ?p2 <uri> .
    }
}
```

By executing the following query, all occurences of the known  should be removed in the known . However I cannot use variables in a delete function. How can I make the above code working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE` needs a template 9what to delete) and a pattern (binds variables).

There is the `DELETE WHERE` operation. https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteWhere

`DELETE WHERE {  ....` is a short form of `DELETE {...} WHERE {...}` with the same `{...}` for template and pattern.